# Deeper question about Cayley's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Cayley's theorem states that there exists an injective homomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow S_n$ for any finite group with $|G|=n$.

Let $\pi: \phi(G) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ be the sign map, sending even permutations to $0$ and odd permutations to $1$. If I compose the functions to get $\pi \circ \phi$, then the kernel of the homomorphism is still a normal subgroup of $G$. So, $\ker(\pi \circ \phi) \trianglelefteq G.$

Does this normal subgroup have any significance in group theory? I'm not sure if there would be a connection to a normal subgroup of elements of even order (I can think of a counterexample to this) or if there's even any remote connection with elements of even order for this group.

I also have speculated this means that simple groups must be isomorphic to a generating set of only even permutations. The idea of the proof would be to assume that the kernel of the composition of functions is equal to the identity. Thus, the nonidentity elements of $G$ must map to odd permutations. However, multiplying two odd permutations gives an even permutation. So, there must be a nontrivial element mapping to an even permutation.

If there's anything I should consider or if there are any mistakes in my argument, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: You should expect that the kernel would be all of $G$.

Comment: @Lubin What about for $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_4 \rightarrow S_4$ by $\phi(x) = (1 2 3 4)^x$? This is the homomorphism into $S_4$, though set of even permutations would be the set $\langle (1 3)(2 4) \rangle$, NOT the entire set.

Comment: The cycles of $\phi(g)$ are just the right cosets $\langle g\rangle\backslash G$, so we can expect there to be an odd $\phi(g)$ (i.e. a proper kernel) precisely when there is a $g\in G$ of even order $|g|$ for which $|G|/|g|$ is odd.

Comment: I’m sorry, but I said “you should expect”. I didn’t say it happened all the time. But what about when $G$ is of odd order?

Comment: Sign representation of $G$ in terms of representation theory.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be of order $n=2m$, $m$ odd, and $g\in G$ of order 2. then the left multiplication by $g$ is a product of $m$ transposition, so its signature is $(-1)^m=-1$.

In general if $g$ is of order $m$, and $k= {n\over m}$ the left multiplication is a product of $k$ cycles of length $m$, so its signature is $(-1)^k$ if $m$ is even, $1$ if $m$ is odd.